# Woocomerce (wordpress) cobra frete de produto digital/download

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugin-wordpress

Tenho uma loja de produtos digitais (eBooks para download), onde o cliente após o pagamento recebe a liberação para baixar o produto, até aí tudo OK.
Hoje cadastrei 4 produtos (físicos) para envio pelo correios, usando PAC ou SEDEX, configurei tudo certo, funciona 100%, mas surgiu um problema com os produtos digitais, agora esta sendo cobrado o FRETE, ou seja, não era para cobrar, já que o arquivo é baixado.
Como posso desabilitar o FRETE para produtos digitais? Já olhei tudo no site e não achei nada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aqui deve está a solução. Você pode ter permitido encomendas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado, na verdade eu só tinha assinalado Baixável / Download, depois que assinalei também o virtual, ele desabilitou o frete! Obrigado

Comment: Que bom que deu certo :))